# Firebase Cloud Function Unit Tests: Https functions don't return promises, how to await them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sinon

If I don't put a setTimeout, my sinon spy console logs before the test() gets called.

```
describe('test', () => {

    it('should test', async () => {

        myFunctions.test(request, response)

        // if I don't put a setTimeout here, my sinon
        // spy console logs before the test() gets called
        setTimeout( () => console.log( stubs.ref.called ), 1 )

    }

}
```